# What are the approaches to trigger ASP.NET Website server side push

Tags: asp.net, signalr

We are implementing Signalr to provide real time updates to browser clients. But we are curretnly stuck as we need to make http server itself (IIS+ASP) detect the changes from database and external services or from any other source without polling?
I believe this should be a common problem with all real time websites (irrespective of what technology is used for server side push SignalR, Comet or WebSync). Please provide what are general approaches used in such situations?

Comment: Research the SQL Broker Service

Answer (score 1):

If you can, raise an event in whatever code is updating your database. Use that event to trigger the message publication.

```
Ready to update database -> Update database
                         -> Publish to WebSync
```

If you can't control the code updating your database, use the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx) class. It lets you define a SELECT statement and then notifies you whenever the results of that query change. Use the notification event to trigger the message publication.

```
Update database -> SqlDependency -> Publish to WebSync
```